# Getting TypeError while using fmin_l_bfgs_b() function

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, scipy

I am using `fmin_l_bfgs_b` function while doing neural style transfer and keep getting

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float32' object is not callable
```

Details of the error block are:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-4699dceebbd9> in <module>()
----> 1 generate_art('/content/nst_images/5.jpg', '/content/nst_images/a.jpg',1, img_height=400)

4 frames
<ipython-input-9-67cbbed20548> in generate_art(content_image_path, style_image_path, iterations, img_height)
     38   for i in range(iterations):
     39 
---> 40     x, min_val, info = fmin_l_bfgs_b(evaluator.loss(x,img_height,img_width,fetch_loss_and_grads),x, fprime=evaluator.grads, maxfun=20)
     41     img = x.copy().reshape((img_height, img_width, 3))
     42     img = deprocess_image(img)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py in fmin_l_bfgs_b(func, x0, fprime, args, approx_grad, bounds, m, factr, pgtol, epsilon, iprint, maxfun, maxiter, disp, callback, maxls)
    197 
    198     res = _minimize_lbfgsb(fun, x0, args=args, jac=jac, bounds=bounds,
--> 199                            **opts)
    200     d = {'grad': res['jac'],
    201          'task': res['message'],

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py in _minimize_lbfgsb(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds, disp, maxcor, ftol, gtol, eps, maxfun, maxiter, iprint, callback, maxls, **unknown_options)
    343             # until the completion of the current minimization iteration.
    344             # Overwrite f and g:
--> 345             f, g = func_and_grad(x)
    346         elif task_str.startswith(b'NEW_X'):
    347             # new iteration

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py in func_and_grad(x)
    293     else:
    294         def func_and_grad(x):
--> 295             f = fun(x, *args)
    296             g = jac(x, *args)
    297             return f, g

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py in function_wrapper(*wrapper_args)
    325     def function_wrapper(*wrapper_args):
    326         ncalls[0] += 1
--> 327         return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
    328 
    329     return ncalls, function_wrapper

TypeError: 'numpy.float32' object is not callable
```

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this? thanks!

Comment: what's the type of `evaluator.loss`

Comment: I would say: use `print()` and `print(type(...))` to check what you have in variables. And check if you use variables in correct order. Maybe you put number in place for function's name and it try to use this numer as function - ie. `1()`

Answer (score 0):

This was a silly error. for fmin_l_bfgs_b, arguments of the loss function have to be passed separately as args = ()